# Unable to Hide HTML Link Based on User Role in ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, webforms

I am developing a ASP.net website for my school project using Visual Studio 2010 and I am applying role based security.

I want to hide a html

element with id="HyperLink1" based on the user role, but, the link that i want to hide still shows up with the wrong credential. Here is a piece of the code from the code behind for my master page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        footerYear.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (Context.User.IsInRole("student"))
                {
                   HyperLink1.Visible = false;
                    Label1.Text = "Hi " + Context.User.Identity.Name + "!";
           }

                else if (Context.User.IsInRole("teacher"))
                {
                    HyperLink1.Visible = false;
                    Label1.Text = "Hi " + Context.User.Identity.Name + "!";

                }

                else if (Context.User.IsInRole("registrar"))
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Hi " + Context.User.Identity.Name + "!";
                    HyperLink1.Visible = false;
                }
            }

            else if (!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Hi Guest!";
            }

        }
```

Comment: debug debug debug, step by step...

Comment: For which role of the user y you are facing the issue?

Comment: for the student role for instance, i want to hide the html link with the id=Hyperlink1, in addition, i also want to hide the link if the user is a Guest i.e not authenticated.

Comment: And did you debug the code? Is it executing properly?

Comment: Yes, there is no error, but the link still shows up even in guest user mode.

Comment: I tried to modify my code as per your suggestions, but there's still no change. By the way, I really am appreciating your efforts to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you simplify your code and flip the conditional:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Label1.Text = Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "Hi " + Context.User.Identity.Name + "!" : "Hi Guest!";
    footerYear.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    HyperLink1.Visible = false;
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
      HyperLink1.Visible = !Context.User.IsInRole("student") && !Context.User.IsInRole("teacher") && !Context.User.IsInRole("registrar");
    }
  }
```